# Visual studio breakpoint - can I set breakpoint that activate another breakpoint,

Tags: visual-studio

Lets say I set a breakpoint with condition, if this break point is hit I want to turn on another breakpoint . Is it possible ?

Comment: not so far as I know, if it's just a temporary thing, you could use a global bool instead.

Comment: Look like an XY problem. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that manually. If the first breakpoint is hit, the program stops at that breakpoint. Now you can go to Breakpoints Window (Alt-F9) and click on the breakpoint you now want to activate.

Below screenshot has both breakpoints enabled. Click on the checkbox on he left to disable a breakpoint. As an example I have added a condition. To add a condition, right-click on the breakpoint and choose Condition..

[image]

As suggested by George, you can have a boolean that is set at the frist breakpoint and use the condition at the 2nd breakpoint to have it break.

Comment: Ye, I imagine this is the closest you're gonna get to a solution, without tampering without code and creating debug-variables.

Answer (score 1):

From visual studio 2022 version 17.0 it should be possible. If you right-click a specific breakpoint, and go into "Conditions...", you can select the checkbox "Only enable when the following breakpoint is hit:", followed by a drop down menu of all the breakpoints in the project.

[image: Showing the Conditions... menu]